# Mozilla addons: My dev account has been hacked

Tags: account

My dev account at Mozilla has been hacked and my addons deleted.

My email has been changed there as well so I cannot do a password reset.

Please advise as to who and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only people who can help you are the addons.mozilla.org sysadmins.  The quickest way to contact them is IRC: irc.mozilla.org, channel #amo.

This is not really on topic for SO.

Comment: Sorry, but I just did not know where to turn to after I kept going around in circles on the mozilla site

Comment: For the record, I got the IRC information from the amo Developer FAQ: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/pages/developer_faq